# promoting TCS/stackexchange

Tags: discussion

have tried to hold my tongue as long as possible to get a feel for this site culture. however, is it just me or does it feel like mass entropy has set in? there is a dribble of new questions daily, but it appears to me it has long been *below* the official stackexchange threshhold for launching groups into beta!

this can be quantified by many site statistics but mainly new questions per month (the main driver of traffic).

the main point of this question is:

> does anyone want to and/or support promoting this site?

---

the TCS archives have lots of great history about amazing promotional projects, lots of enthusiasm around the birth and early stages of the site. but, it seems to have worn off. it also has questions and comments that show some pessimism about the directions of the group, against promotion, etc... however, some of those writers are apparently no longer around or participating.

have many ideas for promoting the site based on extensively surfing it & may edit this post to mention them if it gets some/any support.

to me its sort of *assumed* that participants would want to promote the site, but from reading many past messages, see that its not so simple, "its complicated"....

to those who would be skeptical or a naysayer (nayvoter), please keep in mind that this site is a definitely a premiere and unrivalled site on the internet for theoretical computer science, with lots of highly educated and accomplished academics who have at least *joined* and participated to some small degree. however it also seems to have a lot of users who try it a little and then leave/dont visit it regularly.

there is really nothing like this site anywhere else on the internet. to me, it feels like even with many great accomplishments, the potential is still not fully developed, and its exceptional promise in danger of slowly/gradually fading. the site is not very active compared to some other "places" in cyberspace and especially other stackexchanges.

it does appear that cs.stackexchange has drained off some of the traffic off this site over many months, possibly by being a more friendly atmosphere. some may think that is a good thing or a bad thing (some may not want non-research level questions on here anyway and it may help drain them off), but clearly participation on this site is a key element of its longterm viability....

now, how many places in the world promote computer science, or even more narrowly, theoretical computer science? some element of promotion and, yes, "marketing" is clearly an intrinsic element of science.

was surfing for some resources on promoting science/math and theoretical computer science, but didnt really find any right away. (does anyone know of any?) heres a link on promoting mathematics that turned up from SIAM 1998, talking about movies, recent books, recent media articles in mainstream media like NYT, etc.

[Publicizing Mathematics Today, October 15, 1998](http://www.siam.org/news/news.php?id=887)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm happy to help out with promotions, but I've done a fair bit of it and would like others to get involved as well.

Comment: cool. yeah have seen/come across your past efforts which are impressive. my 1st idea came from recent stackexchange post. to design a few icons as it suggests in this [post](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1619/community-promotion-ads-2013). however the post only has 4 upvotes, and it takes 6 to approve icons. assuming that moderators cannot unilaterally approve them. is that right? anyway am not gonna design the icons until that post is upvoted at least 6, because otherwise it seems unlikely that an icon would be approved by the weak community reaction/support....

Comment: what post is this ?

Comment: linked it! [community promotion ads 2013](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1619/community-promotion-ads-2013)

Comment: also.. do you know how many hits the tcs.se blog gets?

Comment: That blog is kind of defunct right now. Aaron Sterling and Joe Fitzsimmons were in charge of it.

Comment: yeah. still wonder what kind of hits/traffic/exposure it gets.